# How do I get back to the UK if my country is in the COVID "banned countries" list? (Tier 2 Work visa)

Tags: uk, covid-19

### My context:

- Started a job in the UK in late 2019
- Got a Tier 2 (General) work visa
- Got a "*Leave to Remain*" BRP (Biometric Residence Permit) valid for 3 years.
- Rented a flat already.
- Came to my home country in South America just for a field-work (far away from Brazil)
- Last week, had my flights cancelled. There are no outbound flight to the UK at the moment [1]
- UK's [Foreign Office says I'm banned to enter if I have been in my country in the last 10 days.](https://www.gov.uk/guidance/transport-measures-to-protect-the-uk-from-variant-strains-of-covid-19)
- My company is waiting for me, I'm working remotely in the meantime.
- I don't know if my immigration status gives me *residence rights in the UK*
  [image: Screenshot from H.M. Foreign Office web page, link above]

**How do I get back to the UK, my flat, and my work?**
Any suggestions are welcome.

> [1]: * Although, I could travel via USA, stay there for 11 days, and
> then flight to the UK, and make my self-isolation. Can I?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A valid biometric residence permit proves that you are a British resident and you would be eligible to enter UK despite the travel ban.

> From 1 January onwards people with residence rights include: holders of Indefinite Leave to Remain; **holders of existing leave to enter or remain (i.e those with biometric Residence permits) or an entry clearance/visa that grants such leave e.g. students, workers, etc (excluding visit visas)**; holders of EU Settlement Scheme (“EUSS”) leave; those who have rights of entry under the Withdrawal Agreements (including returning residents with a right of residence under the EEA Regulations and EEA frontier workers); family members of EEA nationals with rights under the Withdrawal Agreement.
>
> https://www.gov.uk/foreign-travel-advice/argentina (e.g. for Argentina, but the definitions are the same for all countries)

You would be required to self-isolate for 10 days and follow all public health instructions applicable to you.

Comment: Thanks!!! Didn't see that change until yesterday. They added this explicit definition of "residency rights" just 5 days ago.